# is it possible to load mysqlcheck output into table

Tags: mysql

Just wanted to know, is it possible to load mysqlcheck output into table.

Created table in workbench.

```
use db_test;
CREATE TABLE checktable_status (name varchar(8000), status varchar(10)) ;
```

In BAT file having this.

```
mysql -u root --password=somepassword --port=port_no
insert into db_test.checktable_status
mysqlcheck --check  -u root --password=somepassword --port=port_no --all-databases
```

Comment: Save the output into a file. Then load this file with another query (`SELECT LOAD_FILE(filename)`), parse it and save into the table.

Comment: Thanks for the update, let me try it.

Comment: SELECT  LOAD_FILE('G:\MYSQL_Backup\DBCC\mysqlcheck_log.txt') AS Result; . I have tried and it is retuning single value as null. I  have changed \ to  / as well.

Comment: Got this error.
mysql> SELECT  LOAD_FILE('C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/mysqlcheck_log.txt') AS Result;
+----------------+
| Result         |
+----------------+
| 0x4D75746875   |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: LOAD_FILE loads the whole file as solid string. You must parse it, not save as-is.

Comment: Not sure, I just put one word called mysql inside the file, same error.

Comment: In Linux (etc), the first step would be:  `mysqlcheck ...  >x.txt  2>&1`.  The second step is messy to automate.  Windows has fewer tools to work with;;it may be impossible.